# Android Intent-filter action name vs data scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

In `<intent-filter>`, What is the advantage of specifying `<data android:scheme="">` when one can specify a custom action name which other apps can use?

For e.g.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="foobar" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.myapp.FOOBAR" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

As in what advantage specifying `foobar` scheme gives me? Other apps can also launch my activity by specifying `com.example.myapp.FOOBAR` as Intent action and can send data in Intent extras.

I get that specifying scheme establishes a contract that other app *has* to use that scheme. But is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If a `scheme` is not specified for the intent filter, all the other URI attributes are ignored. That's the basic point you are missing.